# ConnectionString is empty when yielding results

Tags: c#, connection, yield-return

There is a base-class for data-access, that does all connection and sql things:

```cs
public class DataAccessBase
{
    protected DataAccessBase(string connectionString)
    {
        InitSqlConnection(connectionString, byName);
    }

    protected void InitSqlConnection(string connectionString, bool byName = false)
    {
        Connection = new SqlConnection(byName ? ConnectionStringMapper.Current.GetConnectionStringByName(connectionString) : connectionString);
    }

    protected SqlCommand CreateSqlCmd(string sqlQuery)
    {
        return new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, Connection);
    }

    protected DataTable GetDataTable(SqlCommand sqlCmd)
    {
        sqlCmd.Transaction = _transaction;
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd))
            adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        return dataTable;
    }
}
```

Now in a derived class, I wrote a method that retrieves data:

```cs
internal IEnumerable<string> GetData()
{
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder(@" SELECT ... FROM [...] ");

    SqlCommand cmd = CreateSqlCmd(sql);

    DataTable dataTable = base.GetDataTable(cmd);

    foreach(DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        yield return row["FileString"].ToString();
}
```

This method fails. When debugging before `base.GetDataTable`, in `cmd.Connection`, the `ConnectionString` is empty.

But when I use

```cs
return from DataRow row in dataTable.Rows select row["FileString"].ToString()
```

instead of iterating `dataTable.Rows` and `yield return row["FileString"].ToString()`, the `ConnectionString` is correct.

Any idea what's the poroblem here with `yield return`? And why is the `ConnectionString` empty? Imho, it should not matter if yielding or not.

**edit:**

when I move the iterating and yielding to an extra function and calling it, it works. Something like:

```cs
internal IEnumerable<string> GetData()
{
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder(@" SELECT ... FROM [...] ");

    SqlCommand cmd = CreateSqlCmd(sql);

    DataTable dataTable = base.GetDataTable(cmd);

    return _toEnumerable(dataTable);
}

private IEnumerable<string> _toEnumerable(DataTable table)
{
    foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
        yield return row["FileString"].ToString();
}
```

Doesn't make sense - does it?

Comment: Why not use the adapter in 2nd method like first.  GetDataTable is giving an exception so do not use it.

Comment: @jdweng I didn't write the code from `DataAccessBase`, I just have to use the method

Comment: I did some searching and GetTable seem to only be in a WebControl in c# Net Library.

Comment: @jdweng you mean `GetDataTable`? mhh `GetDataTable` is a method in that base-class `DataAccessBase`

Comment: So it is in your own custom class?  Did you look at code to see why it is failing?